# Transmit data over TCP socket between python and Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I'm attempting to trasmit data over TCP socket from python to matlab.
I'm using this python script as TCP client:

```
  #----- A simple TCP client program in Python using send() function -----

import socket
# Create a client socket
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to the server
clientSocket.connect(("192.168.1.40",9090))

# Send data to server
data = "HHH"
clientSocket.send(data.encode())
```

a this code on matlab:

```
 t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 9090, 'NetworkRole', 'server')
fopen(t)
while true
    data = fread(t)
      end
```

The problem is that on the matlab side I see ascii code (72) of the message trasmitted (HHH) but not the letters (H)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMJ5X.png)

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 72 is the ascii code for the character 'H', you just need to convert it to char! For more info about it look at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/unicode-and-ascii-values.html

Comment: If you are wondering why this happens, any message you send through the internet is converted to an array of integers, so character 'H' is converted to its ascii value.

Comment: Hi user1407368. It works but the characters are aligned in vertical and not in orizontal. Any other idea?

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, so I can not try stuff, but if you have them stored in an array you can use the transpose character. For example: A= [72; 72; 72;...] You should be able to convert them to a char string with B = char(A')

Comment: Hi M4Biz, you can also change the way you get data from the socket. For example, if instead of using 'fread(t)' you use 'fgetl(t)' and you add add the character '\n' (character for new line) at the end of the transmitted data you will read it as a line (note that you will still need to cast it to char). If you need more help I can post the code for a simple example that I created a few years ago.

Comment: Hi user1407368.. Yes I'm very intersted to your work. Actually I'm attempting,largely unsuccesful, to redirect in realt time the output of a python code running on a raspberry to matlab by means an ethernet LAN connection between the raspberry PI and the PC with matlab installed. I can easy read all file produced by the raspberry/python code in asyncrhonously mode but I can't read a python output in real, syncrhonous,  time. This is the reason why I've followed the TCP socket way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for a simple TCP communication with Matlab, unfortunatelly i don't have experience with sockets and Python, but can't be much different from this.

Server Side:

```
function tcpServer()
    % Start the TCP server
    t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
    t.TimeOut = 1;

    % Indicate that we want a callback to be generated every time we
    % receive the terminator character (in this case '\n')
    t.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'terminator';

    % Indicate what function do we want to call when the terminator is
    % reached
    t.bytesAvailableFcn = @showMessage;

    try
        disp('Waiting for client...');
        fopen(t);
        disp('Client connected!');
    catch ME
        disp('Oops, someting went wrong!');
        ME.message;
    end

end


% The two parameters that we see here are generated automatically by the
% callback
function showMessage(socketObj, ~)
    data = fgetl(socketObj);
    disp(['Client Said: ', data]);

    fwrite(socketObj, ['Got your message!', char(10)]);
    if strcmp(data,'bye')
         fclose(socketObj);
         disp('Client left :( now I will shut down this socket');
    end
end
```

Client Side:

```
function tcpClient()

    disp('Attempting to connect...')

    % Create a tcp object
    % Note that 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address, anything that you send
    % to this IP address will be sent to your computer, you can replace this
    % IP address with the IP address of your listening device!
    t = tcpip('127.0.0.1', 30000, 'NetworkRole', 'client');

    % Indicate that we want a callback to be generated every time we
    % receive the terminator character (in this case '\n')
    t.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'terminator';

    % Indicate what function do we want to call when the terminator is
    % reached
    t.bytesAvailableFcn = @showMessage;


    % Try to open socket
    try
        fopen(t);
    catch ME
        disp('Oops, someting went wrong!');
        disp(ME.message);
        return;
    end

    disp('Connected!')
    % Wait for some time so the connection has time to start
    pause(0.5)

    % Send a message to the server side
    disp('Greeting the server')
    fwrite(t, ['Hi Server!', char(10)]);
    % char(10) is '\n' (or new line character) indicating where the data
    % that must be received ends.

    % Wait for a couple of seconds so the server has time to see the
    % message
    pause(2);

    % Lets disconnect from the server now
    disp('Saying bye to the server!');
    fwrite(t, ['bye',char(10)]);

    % Close the socket
    fclose(t);
end

% The two parameters that we see here are generated automatically by the
% callback
function showMessage(socketObj, ~)
    data = fgetl(socketObj);
    disp(['Server Said: ', data]);
end
```

Output (Server)

```
Waiting for client...
Client connected!
Client Said: Hi Server!
Client Said: bye
Client left :( now I will shut down this socket
```

Output (Client)

```
Attempting to connect...
Connected!
Greeting the server
Server Said: Got your message!
Saying bye to the server!
```

Comment: Hi user1407368. I thing that you can try your code between two matlab sessions on the same machine. Unfortunately all my issues are related to the format of the data transfereed between the python machine and the Matlab (windows10) machine. Neverthless I'll try your code. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be of more help to you in this topic. Nevertheless, keep in mind that at the end sockets should be quite similar regardless of the platform you are using them on. Good luck!

Comment: Ok. If I'll find a good solution I'll share it on this forum